# Rust formation on Cold rolled carbon steel(SPC 270D)

Tags: materials

We are using Cold rolled Carbon steel(SPC 270)grade. We have observed rust formation due to exposure to air(8-12hrs). The rust analysis resulted 1.6% chlorine whereas allowable limin is <0.01%. Air ppm shows 4ppm for 24hrs. We would like to know the allowable chlorine ppm in air which will cause rust and reasons for it.

Comment: will otherr factors come into play? humidity, temperature, etc

Comment: Hi Mike , we have got the rust in all seasons and temperatures. We have observed the rust formation time varies. High humidity - 4-6hrs , dry condition 12-14hrs